# How to use jQuery with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, raphael, graphael

I try to implement pie chart with raphael library and jquery on angularjs web application. Is there any short way to do this?

In comments you have Fiddle with working code.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HUvqR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conductive line :

```
myapp.directive('rafaelPie',
'$q',
function ($compile, $q) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      values:"=values",
      width:"@width",
      height:"@height",
      labels:"=labels"
    },

    link: function postLink(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    /*Create first pie raphael*/        
    var pie = Raphael(element[0], scope.width, scope.height).pieChart(350, 350, 200, values, labels, "#fff");  
    /*Wath value */
    scope.$watch(scope.values, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            pie.updateyourvalue();
          });
    scope.$watch(scope.label, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            pie.updateyourvalue();
          });
    }
  };
}
```

In your angularview

```
<div id="holder" rafael-pie width="700" height="700" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use directive awesomechart,

```
 <awesomechart type="pie" id='chart2' width="400" height="400" data="data">
    </awesomechart>
```

- see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/xJ69z/8/)
- [official site](http://cyberpython.github.io/AwesomeChartJS/)

Comment: do you have any examples with visualisation
something like that http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html ..like in my fiddle but there is not includ right library of raphael
Otherwise looks nice ...thank you